# Err_Connection_Refused after modifying Varnish default file

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I have properly installed varnish 4. Varnish is on port 80 while apache on port 8080.

After editing `/etc/varnish/default.vcl` and inside `sub vcl_backend_response` writting to cache static files:

```
if (bereq.url ~ “(woff|woff2|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|less)”) {
set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
}
```

I get Err_Connection_Refused

I don't understand what I have done wrong?

Comment: The quotation marks look awfully off to me. Is this intended?

Comment: Can you help  me, now that I indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably copied the code from somewhere on the internet. There are code styling components out there, that replace quotation marks with other characters.

Please mind, there is a subtle but visible difference between `“”` and `""`. Without further error description, you might start and change the quotation marks.

The final result should look like this:

```
if (bereq.url ~ "(woff|woff2|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|less)") {
    set beresp.ttl = 3600s;
}
```

Comment: Hey rollstuhlfahrer  thanks. Since I am a beginner I wanted to ask you For something else. In my website I have dynamic css and js files, which means it they add after .css a =ver+number. How can I cache also those files?

Comment: Looks possible, but please open another question for this. And if you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it!

Comment: Hey @rollstuhlfahrer stackoverflow wants me to post after 90 min. How can I contact you back?